# send outlook email with tables next to each other

Tags: c#, html, css

So yesterday thanks to people on here I learnt how to put two table side by side. However it has now been decided that this information needs to be e-mailed.

So in my c# application I send the e-mail (Outlook) and set the HTMLBody property equal to the html code below.

However when I send the e-mail the second table is display below the first table, how do I get around this?

I've been reading that CSS might be useful however have no knowledge on CSS.

**Side point**

In my first table there is a row which just contains blank cells. Again reading that with CSS this wouldn't be needed but again I do not know how to include CSS in my HTML for my e-mail?

**Example of HTML code**

```
<b><font color='#0033CC'>Sales Report</font></b>
<br><br>
<b>Currency</b>
<br><br>
<table style='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3'>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q1</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q2</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q3</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q4</th><th bgcolor = #0033CC>YoY</th></tr>
<tr><td>CAD</td><td style='text-align: center;'>5.9%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>4.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>3.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>4.3%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>4.3%</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td>CHF</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-1.1%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0.1%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#FF6666'><b><font color='#990000'>-0.4%</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>100%</font></b></td></tr>
</table>

<table style='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3'>
<tr><td><b>Region Agg</b><td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td>EUR</td><td>GBP</td><td>USD</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>Region A</td><td>775</td><td>6,774</td><td><font color='#990000'>-16,786</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>Region B</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>6,459</td></tr>
<tr><td>Region C</td><td>0</td><td>4,328</td><td><font color='#990000'>-4,133</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>Region D</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>4,350</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is not enough space on your view of the email to see the tables side by side? try zooming out on the window. Html should render the same on website or email as far as I am aware

Comment: @Fuzzybear, to be honest the tables are quite small so believe they should fit on the e-mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try HTML attribute `align="left"` for the table also

```
<b><font color='#0033CC'>Sales Report</font></b>
<br><br>
<b>Currency</b>
<br><br>
<table style='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3' align="left">
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q1</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q2</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q3</th><th bgcolor= #0033CC>Q4</th><th bgcolor = #0033CC>YoY</th></tr>
<tr><td>CAD</td><td style='text-align: center;'>5.9%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>4.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>3.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>4.3%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>4.3%</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td>CHF</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-1.1%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0.1%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#FF6666'><b><font color='#990000'>-0.4%</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td><td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>100%</font></b></td></tr>
</table>

<table style='font-size: 10pt; float: left; display: inline-block;' cellpadding='3' align="left">
<tr><td><b>Region Agg</b><td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp</td><td>EUR</td><td>GBP</td><td>USD</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr>
<tr><td>Region A</td><td>775</td><td>6,774</td><td><font color='#990000'>-16,786</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>Region B</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>6,459</td></tr>
<tr><td>Region C</td><td>0</td><td>4,328</td><td><font color='#990000'>-4,133</font></td></tr>
<tr><td>Region D</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>4,350</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues in the past. The problem is that Outlook use MS Word to render HTML not a browser; I am sure you tested it using a browser. Therefore, what you see rendered on the browser will not be identical to what Outlook users will see.

So how to solve this?

1. Provide a link in the email, "View in Browser", so users can click it and see it the way you expect them. You have probably seen this many times yourself and the reasoning behind it is exactly the problem you are having.
2. This option is not as popular as option 1, but I have done this with success in the past. **I**. In MS Word create the template, tables, borders, fonts etc. and save it as html. Basically you are using MS Word as your designer instead of HTML and the browser. **II**. Use this template when sending email. Inject the dynamic content into this template.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use **nested tables**, see below.

> As an aside, I found several problems in your html:
>
> - Sometimes there is `<td><td>` instead of `</td><td>`.
> - You use `&nbsp`, but that must be **`&nbsp;`**.
> - It is best to use quotes for the bgcolor= attributes.
>
> Most of these I already fixed.
>
> I also moved the header text out of the second table, it is now above the table. Reason: the fonts of the headers became unequal because header #1 was outside the table while header #2 was inside the table.

```html
<b><font color='#0033CC'>Sales Report</font></b><br>
<br>
<table>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td>
      <!-- Column #1 -->
      <b>Currency</b>
      <table style='font-size: 10pt;' cellpadding='3'>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <th bgcolor='#0033CC'>Q1</th>
          <th bgcolor='#0033CC'>Q2</th>
          <th bgcolor='#0033CC'>Q3</th>
          <th bgcolor='#0033CC'>Q4</th>
          <th bgcolor='#0033CC'>YoY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CAD</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>5.9%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>4.4%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>3.4%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>4.3%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>4.3%</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>CHF</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>-1.1%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>0.1%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>-0.4%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; background-color:#FF6666'><b><font color='#990000'>-0.4%</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center;'>0%</td>
          <td style='text-align: center; background-color:#99FF99'><b><font color='#009933'>100%</font></b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- Column #2 -->
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <!-- Column #3 -->
      <b>Region Agg</b>
      <table style='font-size: 10pt;' cellpadding='3'>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>EUR</td>
          <td>GBP</td>
          <td>USD</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Region A</td>
          <td>775</td>
          <td>6,774</td>
          <td><font color='#990000'>-16,786</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Region B</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>6,459</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Region C</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>4,328</td>
          <td><font color='#990000'>-4,133</font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Region D</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>4,350</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```